Derivation of $\frac{1}{T_2 *}=\frac{1}{T_2}+\gamma \Delta B$
Ive seen the formula $\frac{1}{T_2 *}=\frac{1}{T_2}+\gamma \Delta B$ thrown out so many times with no explanation, even in textbooks. I am pretty certain it stems from how the dispersion of spins in a sample due to $\vec{B}$ inhomogeneity lead to quicker decay.
If we describe the inhomogeneity by a distribution function $f(\delta)$ which represents the proportion of space with inhomogeneity $\delta$, in the transverse plane in the rotating frame we should see something like
$\vec{M}=M_{xy,0}e^{-\frac{t}{T_2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(\delta)e^{-i \gamma \delta t}d\delta$. But I am uncertain what distribution is assumed in the equation $\frac{1}{T_2 *}=\frac{1}{T_2}+\gamma \Delta B$. I assumed it would've been something simple like a Gaussian but that doesn't seem to be a good choice as it would result in a $t^2$ term in the exponential.
If anyone could help me figure out where this comes from it would be greatly appreciated!

I find the formula nonsensical. It gets mentioned whenever people want to talk about spatial inhomogeneity in the static field over the whole sample. What even is $\Delta B$ in this equation? The field inhomogeneity... where?

@hendlim I was assuming it represented the standard deviation of the inhomogeneity field (considered as a distribution) or something but I've never seen any real context/explanation behind it. It just gets thrown out. One textbook (something like introduction to mri) at least states that its not always valid
